# SwiftUI - How to get the selected index of a list when you have a search?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List in SwiftUI but the problem is that I have a search box.

My code is like this:

```
  List {
    
    ForEach(items.filter {
      self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.term!.contains(self.searchText)
    }, id: \.self) { item in
      Text(item.term!)
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
    .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
      selectedItem = index // 1
    })
  }
```

I need to get the index of the selected item from that list, when the item is selected.

See the line //1? How do I get the `index` there.

Comment: `List` has a selection binding, is that what you need?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry, I am new to swift.

Comment: Nevermind - a better answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by Aperi is not good, because the only elements tappable will be the texts, not the cells.

The correct answer is to wrap the `Text` element as a view of a Button, like shown on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnNWjX8T9JA)...

```
Button(action: {
  // do something()            
}) {
   Text(item.term!)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood your goal (and item is Equatable), then in can be done with

```
}, id: \.self) { item in
  Text(item.term!)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture {
        // above makes complete row tappable inside dynamic content
        // so you have access here to item to find index
        selectedItem = items.firstIndex { $0 == item }
    }
}
.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. You have added `onTapGesture` to the text, so the text is the only element tappable. As the text is on a "table view", the cell will not be tappable, just the text, what is not intuitive. Back to square zero.

Comment: Probably you've forgotten to adapt `frame/contentShape` modifiers - they make entire raw tappable, not only text.